# Find :$\frac{A1}{A}−\frac{A}{A2}$ in the triangle below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For refrence:
In the figure if $MN \parallel AC$ calculate:$\frac{A1}{A}-\frac{A}{A2}$(Answer:$1$)
[image]

My progress:
$\frac{A}{A2} = \frac{AM}{BM}\\
\frac{A1}{A} = \frac{b}{AM}\\
\frac{A2+A}{a} = \frac{A1}{b}\\$

,,,I'm missing some relationship that I haven't seen yet.

$

Comment: You can remove this from the unanswered list (I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangle $ABC$ and $MBN$ are similar, so $$\frac{AC}{MN}=\frac{a+b}a$$ Since $A1$ and $A$ have the same height, $$\frac{A1}{A}=\frac{a+b}a$$
If you draw a height from $B$ to $MN$, say $H$, and to $AC$, say $K$, then $$\frac{BH}{HK}=\frac ab$$
Note that the height from $A$ to $MN$ is equal to $HK$, so $$\frac A{A2}=\frac ba$$
Then $$\frac{A1}A-\frac A{A2}=\frac{a+b}a-\frac ba=\frac aa=1$$

Comment: Thank's for help..

Comment: You are welcome. Note that your last equation is wrong. If the sides are proportional, then the areas are proportional to the square of the sides. $$\frac{A1+A+A2}{A2}=\left(\frac{a+b}a\right)^2$$

Comment: thansks for alert